# How to change the state of single entity without rebuilding list in provider?

Tags: flutter, performance, listview, flutter-provider

I am trying to update the favorite state without having to rebuild the list. I tried different consumer with different value name for favorite button but doesn't work. creating a object of DataModel to get the length and items doesn't work when deleting the item and cause range error. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
Consumer<DataModel>(
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: value.myList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      print('LIST REBUILT');
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(value.myList[index][0]),
                        trailing: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => value.toggleFavorite(index),
                              icon: Icon(
                                value.isFavorite(index)
                                    ? Icons.favorite
                                    : Icons.favorite_border,
                                color:
                                    value.isFavorite(index) ? Colors.red : null,
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => value.deleteItem(index),
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              )
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is it the new state not getting propagated? Can you show the code of your DataModel?

Comment: Everything is working as intended, What I was trying to do was to change the state of single tile when favorite is toggled rather than rebuilding entire list again.

Comment: try to make a stateful widget for List tile, use bool FLAG to keep track of favourite then onClicking the icon update the dataModel and and also the flag but don't notify the listener in data model. It might do the job...